# Polygons sharing a vertex causes gaps in topology

Tags: arcgis-pro, topology, watershed

I have created a floodplain with raster to polygon, smoothing/simplifying, dissolving, and repairing geometry after every geoprocess.

Now I'm doing a topology check for must not have gaps and it has thousands of them. However, there are quite a few gaps that seem to be caused by polygons sharing a vertex and I worry will cause discontinuity in my floodplain or geoprocessing issues for users. These are not multipart polygons, they are single part only.

Attached are some screen caps showing the gaps in the Error Inspector and how it breaks up the floodplain polygon. Is this cause for concern and if so how should I go about addressing this? [image] [image]

Comment: Why are the gaps of concern? Often in floodplain mapping you have holes, they are usually topographic highs in the floodplain, think "small hill in a wide floodplain".

Comment: @Hornbydd in this case, the small polygon in the middle is sharing a vertex with the main stream, but its its own feature when selected. I worry that it might cause topological errors if a user tries performing any geoprocesses on it. Just want to make sure before I share it.